# Ajax category pagination problem

Tags: loop, ajax

I want to make a pagination or load more button for my ajax category display.

Here is my attempt, I have no idea how it can work out. Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );


/*main function of fetching the category selected*/
function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$temp = $DamonQuery;
$DamonQuery= null;
$DamonQuery = new WP_Query();

$cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
$args = array (
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => rand,
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$total = 14;

$thumbnailno = array();

for($x=0;$x<$total;$x++) {
    $thumbnailno[$x] = "http://www.chandamon.com/home/wp-content/uploads/nothumb" . $x . ".png";
}

$DamonQuery->query($args);

$max_page = $DamonQuery->max_num_pages;

ob_start ();

if ( $DamonQuery->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $DamonQuery->have_posts() ) {
        $DamonQuery->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $DamonQuery->post->ID ) ) {
            $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),      'large');
            echo '<div id="post-content"><a href="';
            echo the_permalink() . '" id="' . $post->ID . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'array(255,255)');
            echo '</a></div>';
        }
        else {
            echo  '<div id="post-content"><a href="' ;
            echo   the_permalink() . '" >' . '<img class="nothumbclass" src="' . $thumbnailno[rand(0, 13)]  . '" />';
            echo  '</a></div>';
        }
    }

  /*pagination here*/

    $big = 999999999; 

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'format' => '#',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $DamonQuery->max_num_pages 
    ) );        

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $DamonQuery= null;
    $DamonQuery= $temp;
}

echo '</div>';

$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $response;
die(1);
}
```

Comment: Please work on your readability before adding code to a post. Your code is difficult to read and keep track of. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I know it's a mess...

Comment: this: `get_query_var('paged')` will never give you the results you expect. your ajax request is a new and separate request, there is no `paged` query var set.